# Python Outlook headers

Tags: python, outlook, header

I got a script to extract Gmailheaders. There is a lot of information to extract.
When I try to extract data from outlook it feels like im getting a small part.

The script I currently got is:

```
import win32com.client
import re

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)

messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
rec_time = message.CreationTime

body_content = message.body



while message:
    To = message.To
    Recipients = message.Recipients
    Sender = message.Sender
    address = message.Sender.Address
    cc = message.CC
    Importance = message.Importance
    LastModificationTime = message.LastModificationTime
```

It prints the following fields:

```
print message.subject
print message.CreationTime
print To
print Sender
print address
print cc
print Importance
print LastModificationTime
```

Is there just a limit amount of Outlook headers you can extract or?
I've tryed to look on sources like:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/mailitem-object-outlook
```

I am missing important information like sender IP-adresses. Is there anyway of extracting more information without using a 3partytool?

Thanks!

Edit:
Works:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
for message in messages:
msg = message.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F")
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Currently I have three Outlook Profiles (three email accounts) on my machine. How do we choose which one's Inbox to access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see all MIME headers, read the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F`) using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`.

You can see that property (as well as all other MAPI and OOM properties) using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - click IMessage button.